# Deallocating IBOutlets and instance vars

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, properties, iboutlet

This is something I should have cleared up long ago, but I just need to know the best practice for deallocating in the following scenario.

In my header file I declare a reference to an `IBOutlet` as follows:

```
@interface Test : UIViewController {
    UIButton *_loginBtn;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *loginBtn;
```

And in the implementation file I associate the instance variable to the property and deallocate as follows:

```
@implementation Test

@synthesize loginBtn = _loginBtn;

...

- (void) dealloc {
    [_loginBtn release];
    self.loginBtn = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) viewDidUnLoad {
    [_loginBtn release];
    self.loginBtn = nil;

    [super viewDidUnLoad];
}
```

Am I correct in the deallocating the instance variable and setting the property to `nil` and doing this in both the `viewDidUnLoad` and `dealloc` methods?

Comment: I would actually expect [_loginBtn release]; combined with   self.loginBtn = nil; to crash. The first will release the value but leave it set. The second will then try to release the value again while setting it to nil. That would be a double release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `self.loginBtn = nil;` in `dealloc`, the previous line released it.  It is best not to use the property to release it in dealloc.  The reason for releasing vs setting the property to nil is that the setter is a method call and the class is in the midst of tearing down and things may be unstable.

In `viewDidUnLoad` release any properties that are `IBOutlet`s with `self.theOutlet = nil;`, in this case the `_loginBtn release];` is not needed and redundant.  Also release any other objects that you can easily re-create.

If properties are used they should be used for all accesses in the class with two exceptions: init and dealloc.  In both of these cases the class is partially complete.  In these two cases it is best to use the ivar directly in `init` (if necessary) and `release` in `dealloc`.

Comment: should I just be setting IBOutlets to nil in viewDidUnLoad, or should I also be setting properties such as arrays to nil too (again in viewDidUnLoad)?

Comment: The main issue here is memory and memory warnings.  On a memory warning the system may unload views that are not displaying to free needed memory.  The easiest thing is to set IBOutlets to nil, releasing them, the system will re-load them when re-loads the view.  If you have objects that you can easily recreate consider releasing them as well, you will have to recreate them in viewDidLoad.  The more you help the memory situation the longer your app lives in  the background waiting to be run again.

Comment: If the app is sufficiently memory hungry to get memory warnings when it is in the fore-ground definitely release as much as possible, living and having to reload is better than termination.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is incorrect. By first releasing _loginBtn and then setting the property to nil, you release the instance twice. The correct way to do it is to release _loginBtn and then set _loginBtn to nil.

Comment: You are welcome.One note, since I can't comment on the other answer. In many cases it is preferred to call release instead of assigning nil to the property since the release in the property is implemented using autorelease which delays deallocation and incurs overhead. I would choose release, and then setting the local to nil in order to avoid accidents of later parts of the dealloc method using the property.